# Entity Framework Migrations update metadata not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx), I should be able to update the metadata of the last migration using the command: `Add-Migration <full_name_including_timestamp_of_last_migration>`
Using Entity Framework 6.1.1 in Visual Studio, this does not seem to work. It does not update the existing migration, but creates a new migration with another timestamp in front of the full name of the previous migration.

How can I refresh the metadata of the last migration instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug looks to be fixed in 6.1.2. After upgrading to the new release, I can refresh the metadata, but the command has slightly changed. The command is now:

`Add-Migration <name_of_last_migration_excluding_timestamp>`.

Both commands with and without timestamp failed for me in version 6.1.1.